# How create writable directory by Ant?

Tags: ant

Windows 7 Professional (64 bit), Java 1.8.

I build my project by Ant.

To create folder I use this:

```
<mkdir dir="${var.data.dir.name}" />
```

OK. The folder is created, but it read-only. But I need to create writable folder. How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [setpermissions](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/setpermissions.html) task to fix up the ACL after you create it.

Comment: I add this: `<setpermissions permissions="OWNER_READ,OWNER_WRITE,OWNER_EXECUTE,OTHERS_READ,OTHERS_EXECUTE,GROUP_READ,GROUP_EXECUTE">
     <file file="var.db.current.url"/>
  </setpermissions>` , but I get error: `\build.xml:1396: Problem: failed to create task or type setpermissions
Cause: The name is undefined.`